# Recreating cutup/displace/chopped up effect

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, effects, distort

This may be off-topic, I'll try to make sure it isn't though.

I've found a really nice effect, and I'm trying to recreate it. I don't know much about graphic design, but I've been trying lots of ways to recreate this. I just don't have the knowledge/experience to do it myself. I'm asking for instructions, or help to create a similar effect.

So, here's the example image:
[image: Displace]

I've extracted the colors, and used the same font, with different text to create this:
[image: Ratskin (boring)]

I think I've got the basic image the same, but I have no idea how to make all those cuts/distortion.

I made my image in Sketch, but I quickly realised Sketch wasn't enough to create that effect. So, I exported my design to [an SVG](https://mega.nz/#!Nr5CyIwQ!ZQ_7ka_jcW9bcjheXK6xJ7718gEnRo7CnOBZDgXsEUE), then opened in Adobe Photoshop and Adobe Illustrator. BTW, I've never used either before. After opening it those apps, I preceded to muck around a bunch, and try and get something reasonable. Photoshop didn't seem to be the right thing, so I tried Illustrator. Using Illustrator, I created this, by doing:

- Holding alt, and using the *Knife*, I made a cut
- Then I pushed cmd+shift+A to deselect everything
- After that, I used the *Direct Selection Tool*, to move the shape around

[image: Ratskin (Illustrator)]

As you can see, it's... similar. Now, I could keep doing this manually, but that'd take hours. So, my question is this:

**How can I create this effect without, manually cutting everything to pieces?**

Maybe there isn't a super easy way to do this, but there must be a better way then what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two vertical parallelograms to create two Scatter Brushes with the following options:

[image: Thicker parallelogram]
[image: Thinner parallelogram]

Make three layers, at the bottom the logo, and on top two repeated layers with just the middle path:

[image: Layers]

Each top layer has the same path repeated three times: black, orange and grey stroke, in this order, from bottom to top:

[image: Paths]

Apply the thick brush to the bottom layer paths and the thin brush to the top layer paths.

[image: Animation]

Mask each layer content inside a rectangle

[image: END]

Double click the brushes to modify the options and change the density, size, spacing, etc. To obtain a result more approximate to the example of the question, make the brushes with less density and create other thinner/thick brushes to apply always in different layers. Use the dark brush just in a rectangle around the logo frame.

Comment: After following your instructions, I have created this: https://imgur.com/XZO8NTr

Comment: Looks perfect!  Congratulations